# Php/jquery: How to show value of array loaded elements from db with a loop?

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax

I've written the following php code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM utenti WHERE username = '$username'");
$query_db = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM utenti");
$i = 0;
$array_user = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$dati = array("str"=>array()); 
while ($array_db = mysql_fetch_array ($query_db)) {
    if ($array_user[country] == $array_db[country]) {
        if ($array_user[city] == $array_db[city]) {
            if ($array_user[cap] == $array_db[cap]) {
                if ($array_user[square] == $array_db[square]) {
                    $dati["str"]["n".$i] = "Nome ".$array_db[username];
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

echo json_encode ($dati);
```

I want to load an array using elements from database during a loop:

```
$dati["str"]["n".$i] = "Nome ".$array_db[username];
```

and then to show index and value of this array after an Ajax request:

```
... 
success:function(msg){
    if(msg){
        $.each(msg.str, function(key, value){
            console.log(key + ": " + value);
        });
    }else{
        $("#location").html('Not Available');
    }
```

It doesn't work and I can't find the mistake. Could you help me, please?

Comment: What is there in a console? Any errors?

Comment: No any errors. It's empty. @u_mulder

Comment: ANd `console.log(msg.str)`?

Comment: There's written: Object {n0: "Nome fabio97", n1: "Nome antonino", n2: "Nome Marcuccio", n3: "Nome silvia"} @u_mulder

Comment: And your `$.each` is not logging anything?

Comment: No now It works but if I write: `$("#location").html(key + ": " + value);` it shows only the last element *n3: Nome silvia* and not everyone. Why? How  can I fix? @u_mulder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing your code

```
$.each(msg.str, function(key, value){
    console.log(key + ": " + value);
});
```

works fine.

Then, your attempt `$("#location").html(key + ": " + value);` means that everytime contents of `#location` will be **overwritten**.

Instead, you can use `append()`:

```
$.each(msg.str, function(key, value){
    console.log(key + ": " + value);
    $("#location").append(key + ": " + value);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I write: `$("#location").html((Object.keys(msg.str).map(x => msg.str[x]).join("<br />")));` and it works. What the differences between this instruction and the one with append? @u_mulder

Comment: `append()` appends data to div on each iteration. And your code implodes (`joins`) all data from object and put it in a div __once__.